# TriggeredSend on subscription + information mail for subscription

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

In the past I used the WebCollect to get subscribers into SFMC data extensions. I was asked about the possibility to send out a mail on a subscription with the WebCollect form.

As far as I understood this is not possible from the initial solution so I am trying to play around with landing pages + AMPscript + triggered sends.

This is working good so far but there is an additional request to also send out a mail to a "special" contact as soon as a new subscriber subscribed. After some reflections I don't think that this is possible just with triggered sends.

Is there nevertheless a way to have a mail send to a when someone subscribed ? Perhaps with automation and queries which check if there is someone new or so ?

Does anybody has an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For real time triggered sends, you have a few choices.

UI possible solutions:

1. [Welcome emails](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/) from a list - This only works on lists, not data extensions and will send a specific email to all new entries to the specified lists.  Please be aware there is little in the way of customization on who, why and how for this send in the UI.
2. [Smart Capture form](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/) - This will allow you to collect the information and create an API call to the triggered email of your choice.  This is basically removing the HTML and AMPscript development required and instead creating via the UI.  This allows a bit more control on who why and how, but is still limited in the possibilities without custom development.
3. [Journey Builder](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/) - By creating a Journey event that is triggered via API you can have the person subscribed and then entered into a Journey, providing full custom control not just in who gets what, but also allows you to add more to it and allow a full journey instead of just a single email.  This will take some development work to set up the API call.

Development solutions:

1. [Create an API call with the form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm) - if you are able to have your server-side processing page send an API call, you can call a triggered email via both REST and SOAP API.  This will also allow you full customization as you can make your filters and other logic right on the server level with a script of your choice.
2. [Create 2 automations that call each other](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-starting-an-automation-with-ssjs/) - Basically you would create an infinite loop with 2 automations that constantly check the subscriber list for new subscribers and then call a User Initiated email if there is anyone new.  This would require development either in SSJS or AMPscript as well as filters, queries, and multiple data extensions. (shout out to @AdamSpriggs for his documentation on this script)

The simplest solution, not real time, is to create an hourly running Automation - this will search the DE and find new subscribers and then run an UI email to send to them. Similar to #2 above, but only a single automation and runs hourly.